# Auto open fullscreen on another monitor

Tags: javascript, browsers

I have been asked by a local company to build an internal system using asp (as all their databases are msAccess and they are not interested in changing).  At the moment they are having to visit two separate internal addresses, manually move one browser window to a new monitor and then F11 to fullscreen it.

I want to automate that process so as soon as they load the first address, a second window automatically pops up on the second monitor and fullscreens itself.  This is internal only and will be expected behaviour.

I know it can be done as I see it with those tech support scam websites every day, but I have no idea how to do it.

Can anyone help?  It doesnt have to be an asp solution, I can easily load the asp within an iframe if another language has to be used.

Comment: What browser/OS are you using? "I see it with those tech support scam websites" - they might spawn a new window, but I've never seen them go "full screen" (without prompting) or open on a different monitor? You could perhaps do this with an [AutoHotKey](http://ahkscript.org/) (Windows) script?

Comment: One I see all the time is a typical BSoD inside a browser window so when its fullscreened, it looks like a normal browser, except you cant click close, minimise etc as its just a picture.  When it opens, it automatically fullscreens.  The only way to close it is either ctrl+w or f11 then X.  I will be using chrome, so I guess I just need to open the screen on the other monitor -position doesn't matter- & just auto fullscreen it.  Position will then take care of itself.

Comment: Can you install scripts/plugins on the local machine?

Comment: Yes, I will have full local access to all the machines to install as appropriate.

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/a/57303963/1497139